# What is virtual polymorphism?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, oop

**I know about polymorphism and the keyword virtual** in C#.net, but i don't know what is **Virtual polymorphism**, I was asked this question in a interview yesterday.

Thank you

Comment: I strongly suspect they meant polymorphism with virtual functions.

Comment: It sounds like someone does not have clue about either.

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar: Is there any other way? (besides using interfaces of course).

Comment: @leppie - do you mean is there any other way to achieve polymorphism than virtual functions and interfaces? Operator Overloading is one I can think of.

Comment: Never heard of it... When at the receiving end of interviewees I hear about 'static' and 'dynamic' polymorphism, viz. overloading and overriding. The crux of polymorphism is the ability to invoke different blocks of code using a Base/Interface type reference. I'd say unless it was a trick question.. look somewhere else for a job.

Comment: Looks like the interviewer wanted to appear smarter than you... but that's BS, there's no such thing as "virtual polymorphism"

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar: Overloading and especially operator overloading is not polymorphism. It is simply a 'generic' method (not generic in .NET/C# terms).

Comment: @Leppie - interesting!! But event though it is 'generic' method doesn't it allow polymorphic treatment of types? I read it here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming.

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar: If it uses polymorphism inside the overloaded method, that's a different story. Overloading by itself has no relation to polymorphism. Wikipedia is incorrect about operator overloading (in terms of how it works on .NET anyways, dunno about other languages). Good example is `object`'s `==` operator. If either instance is `object` (statically typed) it will simply call `ReferenceEquals` with complete disregard for polymorphism. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Disputed for more info.

Comment: @leppie, I believe that it would depend on what polymorphism means! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism does say that overloading is ad hoc polymorphism! However, I suppose that your are right from C# perspective: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(v=VS.100).aspx (going by creator's documentation).

Comment: @VinayC: Still wrong. Unless I get a counter-proof, I will stick to my answer.

Comment: Thank you guys, for all your answers, even though i know the answer that no such thing as virtual polymorphism exists, i still don't know what to answer the question, ahh! I suppose it should be a discussion in an other forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either....

They meant "runtime polymorphism" (late binding) (so as to know if you know the difference between compile-time and runtime polymorphism).

Or...

The question was fired to confuse you.

Comment: Yes, i suppose the interviewer was trying to confuse me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing called virtual polymorphism.

You can achieve polymorphism by using virtual methods in C#.

That means if you declare a method `virtual` in base class you can `override` that method in child/derived classes to change it's behavior.

```
class Base
    {
        public virtual void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from base");
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from derived");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are concepts like:

- [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)
- [virtual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)
- Just [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), or [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_inheritance)

I've never heard about virtual polymorphism. In most modern programming languages, these concepts are strongly related. IMHO, it's very academic to distinguish them (I mean: inheritance, virtual inheritance, polymorphism, subtype polymorphism).